# Prevent click on another button jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to prevent click another button if first is clicked...

Example
http://jsfiddle.net/C5AVH/3/

```
  $(function(){ 
     $('.vote_like').one('click',function(){
     $('.vote_dislike').removeClass('vote_dislike');
     alert('Done!')
   });

   $('.vote_dislike').one('click',function(){
    $('.vote_like').removeClass('vote_like');
    alert('Done!');
    });
   });

    <a href="#" class="vote_like">Like</a> - 
    <a href="#" class="vote_dislike">Dislike</a>
```

When you click **Like** button i want disable click on **Dislike** button and inversely...

im try with removing class but seems that not working...

```
$('.vote_like').removeClass('vote_like');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the click handler

```
$(function () {
    $('.vote_like').one('click.like', function () {
        $('.vote_dislike').off('click.like');
        console.log('like!')
    });
    $('.vote_dislike').one('click.like', function () {
        $('.vote_like').off('click.like');
        console.log('dislike!');
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/DYhma/)

Comment: This will still require you to handle the click because it's an anchor and will do something you don't want. As long as you're canceling it, something has to be done. You'd also have to re-register the events if you wanted to allow switching.

Comment: One can still make the anchors return false on click without the namespace, no?

Answer (score 1):

Because you've attached the `.one` handler to each button, it will still be executed at most one time according to the [jquery docs](http://api.jquery.com/one/). To prevent the click you must remove the handler after one is clicked.

```
     $('.vote_like').one('click',function(){
     $('.vote_dislike').off();
     alert('Done!')
   });

   $('.vote_dislike').one('click',function(){
    $('.vote_like').off();
    alert('Done!');
    });
   });

    <a href="#" class="vote_like">Like</a> - 
    <a href="#" class="vote_dislike">Dislike</a>
```

But better yet, why not just attach the `one` handler to both elements and check which was clicked:

```
  $(function(){ 
     $('.vote_like,.vote_dislike').one('click',function(){  
     if($(this).is('.vote_like')){
         //set data for like
     }
     else{
         //set data for dislike
     } 
     //make ajax call
   });
```

Comment: because im call ajax function after clicking than data is stored in database with php...

Comment: Thats okay, you can control which data you wish to store inside the function, I've updated my post

Answer (score 0):

Anchors don't have a way to disable them, so you'd either need to remove the anchor or set a boolean in your javascript to track if it's been clicked.

Or, you can convert them into actual `button` elements, play with the `disabled` state.

Or you can use jquery to add custom `data` attributes to the anchor to track if it's "disabled"

Answer (score 0):

Can use one handler for both buttons and remove click handler within it for both

```
var btns=$('.vote_like, .vote_dislike').on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var isLikeBtn=$(this).is('.vote_like');
    /* remove click handler for both, remove class from other button */
    btns.off('click').not(this).removeClass( isLikeBtn ? 'vote_dislike' : 'vote_like');
});
```

Since using `off` on both would be equivalent of using `one`

Answer (score 0):

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/C5AVH/5/)

```
$(function(){ 
    $('.vote_like, .vote_dislike').on('click',function(){
        $(this).siblings('.vote_like, .vote_dislike').add($(this)).prop('disabled',true);
        if ($(this).hasClass('vote_like')) {
            /* Do like things */     alert('like');
        }else{
            /* Do dislike things */  alert('dislike');
        }
    });
});
```